# How Insert column looping in datagridview VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, loops, datagridview

[image: Please Check Image]

I ask for vb net datagridview,

How do you fill in the "aging" column with status on or off ...

If SC01 has three POS, where one of the POS has ttl_stat OFF, the "aging" column will be filled OFF.

And if SC02 only has one POS and ttl_stat on then the "aging" column will also be ON

Thank you

Comment: First guess is to add an “Expression” column to a `DataTable`…. [DataColumn.Expression Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in SQL:

```
SELECT *,  
        (SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(  
         (SELECT t2.kd_store FROM test_stack t2
            WHERE t.kd_store = t2.kd_store 
            AND t2.ttl_stat = 'OFF'
          )
        ) THEN 'OFF' ELSE 'ON' END
       ) AS Aging
FROM test_stack t
```

Comment: thank you for helping,
so how do i input to vb net for that sql script?

Comment: Hm where is your data of the grid coming from? I thought you already load it from a database

Comment: so the datagridview comes from when I import master data using csv.
This is the source when I import CSV.

Comment: Hi @Alex help me please .. :(

Comment: sorry I was not online last weekend. will respond later

Answer (score 0):

Sub uploadmaster()

```
    Try
        Dim columnHeaderStyle As New DataGridViewCellStyle()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 28
        columnHeaderStyle.Font = New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
        DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = columnHeaderStyle



        Dim Filename As String
        Filename = "D:\LOG_Monitoring\" + Format(Now, "ddMMyyyy") + "\Master.txt"

        Dim FileImported As New System.IO.StreamReader(Filename)
        Dim itemSeparate As Char

        itemSeparate = ";"
        While FileImported.Peek() <> -1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(FileImported.ReadLine().Split(itemSeparate))
        End While

        For Each x As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If Not x.IsNewRow Then
                If x.Cells("stat_printer").Value = "OFF" Or x.Cells("stat_cd1").Value = "OFF" Or
        x.Cells("stat_cd2").Value = "OFF" Or x.Cells("stat_network").Value = 1 Then
                    x.Cells("ttl_stat").Value = "OFF"
                Else
                    x.Cells("ttl_stat").Value = "ON"
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Label1.Text = "SYNC DATA MASTER....!!!!"
    Catch ex As Exception
        ''MsgBox("Please Check Master Data", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```